# Android - SherlockActionBar - What is benefit of using SherlockFragments?

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I get the benefits of the SherlockActionBar 100%.

What is the benefit of SherlockFragments though? You have your main Activity /FragmentActivity which is hosting all of your other fragments etc. and extends SherlockActivity / SherlockFragmentActivity.

If you can get reference to your parent Activity in the `onAttach(Activity parentActivity)` Fragment method, and use methods like `parentActivity.getActionBar().setTitle(title)` etc. Why would you choose to make those Fragments Sherlock fragments?

Quite new to this Sherlock stuff and any insight would be very appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would you choose to make those Fragments Sherlock fragments?

So you can use `setHasOptionsMenu()`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, and `onOptionsItemSelected()` in the fragment.
As fragments come and go from the screen, Android will automatically add and remove those fragments' action bar items from the action bar.

Answer (score 1):

SherlockFragments provide backward compatability (i.e. pre- HoneyComb) for a lot of the newer functionality. Fragments typically only work for post-HoneyComb devices.

Comment: Why not just use the Fragment support library?

Comment: ActionbarSherlock has all the functionality of the support library included, as well as a whole bunch of other useful stuff. Unless you are not intending to use action bars, or are not targeting Gingerbread devices, I cannot think of a good reason **not** to use ActionbarSherlock. And, if you are using it, you will need to specify SherlockFragments rather than simple fragments.

Comment: Cheers for the info, I'll use them! :)